# Ordering a list of items based on their second value

Tags: python, list, set

The function needs to be able to take a list such as:

```
[("Alice", [1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]), ("Bob", [3, 1, 5, 3, 2, 5]), ("Clare", [2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2]), ("Dennis", [5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4]), ("Eva", [4, 5, 3, 5, 5, 3])]
```

and process the information to order it by the total of each of the results, and output the data in the original format but starting with the person with the lowest score and working downwards and it has to break ties using the first value in each. (The first result for each person)

What I have written so far can take one entry and work out the total score:

```
def result(name, a):
    a.remove(max(a))
    score = 0
    for i in a:
        score = score + i
    return score
```

But I need to be able to adapt this to take any number of entries and be able to out more than just the total.

I know I need to have the function work out the total scores but be able to keep the original sets in tact but I don't know how to interact with just one part of an entry and iterate through all of them doing the same.

I'm using Python 3.4.

Comment: why do you remove `max(a)` from the list? your description doesn't mention it.

Comment: That was for a separate criteria, the scores are for a sailing competition and their scoring removes the worst placing for each competitor before adding up the scores

Comment: you should either explain it then, or remove it from the demo code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood your question properly, you'd like to sort the list, and have the sort order defined by the sum of the numbers provided in each tuple. So, Alice's numbers add up to 7, Clare's add up to 15, so Alice is before Clare.

`sorted()` can take a function to override the normal sort order. For example, you'd want:

```
sorted(data, key=lambda entry: sum(entry[1]))
```

This will mean that in order to work out what's bigger and smaller, `sorted()` will look at the sum of the list of numbers, and compare those. For example, when looking at Alice, the lambda (anonymous) function will be given `("Alice", [1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1])`, and so `entry[1]` is `[1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]`, `sum(entry[1])` is then `7`, and that's the number that `sorted()` will use to put it in the right place.

Comment: This doesn't handle "break ties using the first value in each".

Comment: @ScottHunter: Tiebreaker on names: `sorted(data, key=lambda entry: (sum(entry[1]), entry[0]))`.  Throwing out the highest score and tiebreaker:   `sorted(data, key=lambda entry: (sum(entry[1])-max(entry[1]), entry[0]))`.  At which point I'd probably make it shorter by renaming `entry` as `x`.

Comment: Question could be read as breaking ties on the first *score*, but it isn't very clear.

Comment: I did mean break ties using the first score but what is there so far is incredibly helpful

Comment: @Green:  Tiebreaker on first score: `sorted(data, key=lambda entry: (sum(entry[1]), entry[1][0]))`